# Can I use socket.io on apigee APIS Proxies?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, apigee

I was trying to figure out how do this question, but I saying simple, is it possible to use the `node_module` `socket.io` on `apigee APIs Proxies`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of the present day, you can not use socket.io on Apigee node implementation. The node container in Apigee sits behind a standard Apigee proxy. Apigee proxies are accessible over plain http or https and allow all sort of functionalities one needs to expose APIs or control access or generate analytics . And the node piece behind the proxy can then offer a place to host more hairy implementation logic.